# Check if a specific class present in HTML using beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script and want to check if a particular class is present in html or not.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def makesoup(u):
    page=requests.get(u)
    html=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")
    return html
html=makesoup('https://www.yelp.com/biz/soco-urban-lofts-dallas')

print("3 star",html.has_attr("i-stars i-stars--large-3 rating-very-large")) #it's returning False
res = html.find('i-stars i-stars--large-3 rating-very-large")) #it's returning NONE
```

Please guide me how I can resolve this issue?If somehow I get title (title="3.0 star rating") that will also work for me. Screenshot of console HTML [image]

```
<div class="i-stars i-stars--large-3 rating-very-large" title="3.0 star rating">
  <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/8a6fc2d74183/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="3.0 star rating">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_attr` is a method that checks if an element has the **attribute** that you want. `class` is an attribute, `i-stars i-stars--large-3 rating-very-large` is its **value**.

`find` expects [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), not class values. So you should instead use `html.find('div.i-stars.i-stars--large-3.rating-very-large')`. This is because you are looking for a `div` with **all** of these classes.

Comment: Still returning None.

Comment: Please try `find_all` instead of `find` and tell me if this behaviour persists.

Comment: it's returning empty list with find_all

Comment: That could only mean that this element doesn't have these classes that we think they have. Maybe one of them is mispelled or there's a problem with the HTML file from the request?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot, on printing html I am finding "i-stars i-stars--large-3 rating-very-large" there but why find function is not getting it ? :(

Comment: Yes, it is indeed quite odd. Maybe you should print the whole `html` variable  after invoking `makesoup`. Might give us a clue of what's happening.

Comment: same. Is there any alternative to check class or somehow I get value of alt ("3.0 star rating") using class offscreen?

Answer (score 2):

Was having similar problems getting the exact classes. They can be brought back as a dictionary object as follows.

```
html = '<div class="i-stars i-stars--large-3 rating-very-large" title="3.0 star rating">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
find = soup.div
classes = find.attrs['class']
c1 = find.attrs['class'][0]
print (classes, c1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def makesoup(u):
    page=requests.get(u)
    html=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")
    return html
html=makesoup('https://www.yelp.com/biz/soco-urban-lofts-dallas')
res = html.find(class_='i-stars i-stars--large-3 rating-very-large')
if res:
    print("3 star", 'whatever you want print')
```

out:

```
3 star whatever you want print
```

Comment: It's working but it's printing "3 star whatever you want print" every time. How can I check class="i-stars i-stars--large-3 rating-very-large" is inner class of class="rating-info clearfix" ?